# High CPU Usage and hangs randomly with HHVM

Tags: centos, nginx, central-processing-unit, hhvm

I'm using phpbb on Centos 7 with 512mb of ram and 1 core.

And I'm having randomly hangs and high cpu usage when I get some url of my clean phpbb installation.

This is my server.hdf file:

```
idFile = /run/hhvm.pid

Server {
    Port = 9000
    Type = fastcgi
    SourceRoot = /home/deploy/www/mypage
    ExposeHPHP = 0
}

Log {
    Level = Error
    UseLogFile = true
    File = /var/log/hhvm/hhvm-error.log
    Access {
        * {
            File = /var/log/hhvm/hhvm-access.log
            Format = %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b
        }
    }
}

Repo {
    Central {
        Path = /var/log/hhvm/.hhvm.hhbc
    }
}
```

And this is my nginx.conf php settings:

```
index index.php index.html index.htm;

try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;

location ~ .(hh|php)$ {
    fastcgi_keep_conn on;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

I'm using HipHop VM 3.8.0-dev (rel) with Nginx 1.8.0 and mariadb, any clues?

Everything seems alright in log files :(

Thanks!

Comment: for e. g. : http://etcinsider.com/blog/2015/05/11/hhvm-is-futex-abuser/ so I don't think it can be considered really production ready for now

Comment: Hangs of the entire machine?

Comment: No hangs, just extra CPU burn out. And sometimes it crashes too. )

Comment: How much swap do you have, and how much is being used?